# SQL Injection for array of mixed vulnerability and non vulnerability queries

Tags: java, arrays, sql-injection

Below persistent code has SQL vulnerability. 
strSetStatement[1], strSetStatement[2] and strSetStatement[6] is setting parameters based on genSetStatement method sending. Which can be untrusted data. I am facing to fix this mix of simple queries and parameterized queries.

SQL Injection vulnerable code

```
    public class SQLInjection{

        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {

            String[] strSetStatement = new String[6];
            PreparedStatement m_statement;
            String url = "DBURL";
            Connection conenction = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");

            m_statement = conenction.prepareStatement("SET CHARACTER_SET 'UTF8_FTCS'");

            // Setting DB Initial parameters | setting limits for queries 
            String strMatch = "100";
            String strTime = "100";
            String strRank = "2:1";

            genSetStatement(strSetStatement, strMatch, strTime, strRank);

            boolean logQuery = true;

            if (logQuery) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
                    setlogComment(m_statement, strSetStatement[i]);
            }

        }

        private static void genSetStatement(String[] strSetStatement, String strMatch, String strTime, String strRank) {

            strSetStatement[0] = "SET SHOW_MATCHES 'FALSE';";
            strSetStatement[1] = "SET MAX_SEARCH_ROWS " + strMatch + ";";
            strSetStatement[2] = "SET MAX_EXEC_TIME " + strTime + ";";
            strSetStatement[3] = "SET SERVER_REPORT_TIME " + FTSSearchConst.SERVER_REPORT_TIME + ";";
            strSetStatement[4] = "SET SEARCH_MEMORY_SIZE " + FTSSearchConst.SEARCH_MEMORY_SIZE + ";";
            strSetStatement[5] = "SET THESAURUS_NAME 'FULTEXT';";
            strSetStatement[6] = "SET RELEVANCE_METHOD '" + strRank + "';";

        }

        private static void setlogComment(PreparedStatement stmt, String strSetState) throws SQLException, IOException {


            stmt.executeQuery(strSetState); // SQL injected area
        }

    }
```

I am trying to do below by adding '?' in strSetStatement[] array. and check if query has '?' in setlogComment method, but how to identify the exact parameter and bind variables to it ?

```
   strSetStatement[1] = "SET MAX_SEARCH_ROWS " + ? + ";";
```

```
    private static void setlogComment(PreparedStatement stmt, String strSetState) throws SQLException, IOException {

            if(strSetState.contains("?")){
                stmt.setString(1, arg1);            
            }
            stmt.executeQuery(strSetState); 
        }
```

Comment: Does your code compile and run at all?  You have undefined variable `arg1` in `setlogComment`, and declared `strSetStatement` as array of 6 elements while setting 7 elements.  None of the QL queries contains `?` so what's the use of calling `setlogComment`?

Comment: @AlexRudenko I have updated my question.  setlogComment execute all the statements that I added in strSetStatement array.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Hope you are clear of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caution: I'm not sure for which SQL version/dialect you're going to run these queries, this should be some Full-Text-Search extension.

The purpose of the following code is to get rid of the issues detected in your code snippet, however, you may need to update it appropriately in case of any error.

1. The code has been reactored to get rid of redundant methods/variables.
2. Queries at indexes 1, 2, 6 have been updated to include `?` for outer parameters.
3. Type of `matchRows` and `execTime` parameters has been changed to `int`
4. Parameters for the `PreparedStatement` are set and the queries are executed inside main loop.

```java
public class SQLInjection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {

        String[] strSetStatement = {
            "SET SHOW_MATCHES 'FALSE';",
            "SET MAX_SEARCH_ROWS ?;",
            "SET MAX_EXEC_TIME ?;",
            "SET SERVER_REPORT_TIME " + FTSSearchConst.SERVER_REPORT_TIME + ";",
            "SET SEARCH_MEMORY_SIZE " + FTSSearchConst.SEARCH_MEMORY_SIZE + ";",
            "SET THESAURUS_NAME 'FULTEXT';",
            "SET RELEVANCE_METHOD ?;"
        };

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("DBURL", "", "");

        PreparedStatement m_statement = connection.prepareStatement("SET CHARACTER_SET 'UTF8_FTCS'");
        m_statement.executeQuery();

        // Setting DB Initial parameters | setting limits for queries 
        int matchRows   = 100;
        int execTimeSec = 100;
        String strRank  = "2:1";

        boolean logQuery = true;

        if (logQuery) {
            for (int i = 0; i < strSetStatement.length; i++) {
                PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(strSetStatement[i]);
                if (i == 1) {
                    stmt.setInt(1, matchRows);
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    stmt.setInt(1, execTimeSec);
                } else if (i == 6) {
                    stmt.setString(1, strRank);
                }
                stmt.executeQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```